# Can SSL Wildcards have multiple/nested levels of wildcard?

Tags: security-certificate

I know that an SSL wildcard certificate (`*.example.org`) can be used to support many names under the domain (`a.example.org`, `b.example.org`, `c.example.org`). I also know that the * is only good for matching a single level of name. That is, `*.example.org` will not work on `a.b.example.org`.

What if I used a certificate with the name *.*.example.org? I'd like to build a certificate with the following name configuration:

```
CN=example.org
subjectAltName=DNS:example.org, DNS:*.example.org, DNS:*.*.example.org, DNS:*.*.*.example.org
```

I've tried building a few like this as self-signed certificates, but I've not had good results. For example, chrome tells me "Server's certificate does not match the URL."

Is it possible to have nested wildcards in a certificate, or do the popular browsers not support this?

**edit** I believe it's possible to build a cert like this: I've done so with OpenSSL. It just looks like browsers understand it. I was hoping for confirmation of that, or if I'm lucky, a "here's how you do it."

Comment: What would be the point? why not just use hyphens to separate...

Comment: Because that's a "wrong" use of DNS (in my case). I might have an application that has multiple servers. So, I might create a DNS subzone "app1.example.com" and put all my app1 servers behind it. I could just get another wildcard for `*.app1.example.com`, but if I could get a cert with `CN=*.example.com, SAN=[example.com *.*.example.com]`, I could put that on a load balancer and have it work for most situations.

Answer (score 1):

Some SSL cert providers do something similar to this by providing a "subject alternative name" feature within their wildcard certs.

Digicert apparently does this but I'm not sure if Verisign does.

http://www.digicert.com/welcome/wildcard-plus.htm

Comment: It doesn't appear that Digicert allows you to put another wildcard in as a SAN, at least, their documentation doesn't read that way.